# Why does JS Bin tell me potential infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, increment

For this code:

```
var Obj={};

for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
  var add = prompt("add stuff in me!");
  var last = Obj.length;
  Obj.last = "add";
}

console.log(Obj);
```

**JS Bin** insists that is is potentially an infinite loop and that it will terminate subsequently.

Comment: What in the world is the code supposed to do?  I can't see how it actually does anything useful either so maybe its more productive to concentrate on that endeavor.  `Obj.length` is `undefined` in this code so all this code is ever doing is prompting for a string that is not used and then setting `Obj.last = "add"` six times.  I'd really suggest you describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just cut and pasted that exact code into CodePen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNgYmm) and it didn't complain at all. In fact it ran it and showed me six dialog boxes then stopped. So, either that *isn't* the code causing the problem or you've been partaking of some illicit substances :-)

Comment: nothing happen except six dialog box displayed on Codepen ^^

Comment: I added // noprotect to JS Bin and it loops but doesn't log to consosle.

Comment: Well... it IS potentially an infinite loop (Has the potential)

Comment: This makes more sense ;) http://jsbin.com/hevutejela/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks @VIDesignz that runs better, although I still get the error and it looks like it's a problem with the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSBin implements infinite loop protection by injecting code into your Javascript which *times* the loops (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EA74ODg1qKE), at about the two-minute mark). Basically, if a loop takes more than a predefined time, it will exit it with the warning and continue the code.

Your problem *here* is that you are waiting for user input within your loop so, unless the user can enter those six values within the timeout threshold, it will consider the loop to be infinite. You can verify this by changing the user input line into:

```
var add = "x"; // prompt("add stuff in me!");
```

Running that in JSBin shows no issues, because the user input is not delaying the loop.

The fix for this is to add `// noprotect` to the line to stop JSBin from erroneously considering it infinite:

```
for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){ // noprotect
```

---

Added note: Although the linked video says the timeout is about a second, the [code](https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect/blob/master/lib/loop-protect.js) seems to disagree. It states that the threshold is only a tenth of a second:

```
/**
* Injected code in to user's code to **try** to protect against infinite
* loops cropping up in the code, and killing the browser. Returns true
* when the loops has been running for more than 100ms.
*/

loopProtect.protect = function protect(state) {
  loopProtect.counters[state.line] = loopProtect.counters[state.line] || {};
  var line = loopProtect.counters[state.line];
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();

  if (state.reset) {
    line.time = now;
    line.hit = 0;
    line.last = 0;
  }

  line.hit++;
  if ((now - line.time) > 100) {//} && line.hit !== line.last+1) {
    // We've spent over 100ms on this loop... smells infinite.
    loopProtect.hit(state.line);

    // Returning true prevents the loop running again
    return true;
  }

  line.last++;
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Great thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what JS Bin is detecting, but there is a potential infinite loop there.

The variable *i* is not declared, so it is by default a global variable. The loop body calls a function, which could change the value of *i* (e.g. `i = 0;`) so that it never reaches the end, and so the loop would be infinite.

Alternatively, *i* could be defined as a constant (`const i;`), which would prevent the value from changing, again making it an infinite loop.